# how get only image data from multipart/form-data attachments on couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I've uploaded standalone attachments on couchdb. The attachments are images jpeg. If I try to get this attachments with curl:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/dbname/docId/imgName'
```

I obtain MIME response in format:

```
--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="img"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...binary data...
```

How I can get only binary data without parsing MIME response?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. Try to re-upload your attachment with the proper MIME type (`image/jpeg`):

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbname/docId/imgName --data-binary @img.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
```

It seems like your was uploaded as form data and not *plain* data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved send image inline in base64. In this way with

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/dbname/docId/imgName'
```

I obtained directly the binary data. (Note that I download standalone attachments and not base64 inline attachments)